# Swipable Linear/Relative Layout

Tags: java, android

I am relatively a beginner in android. I was trying to build a similar app as the calculator shown below. The problem that I am facing is regarding deciding how to swipe the scientific part of the calculator to the right as shown in the image. It is certainly not a `ViewPager`, or is it? I cannot conclude how to build this feature. Shall I use a `RelativeLayout` and use my own java code to make it swipable. If so then how? Please help me regarding **how to make the Scientific part of the calculator swipable**?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use `ViewPager`, you can use [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

You can use `ViewPager`. You should create two fragments, for example `BasicButtonsFragment` and `ScientificButtonsFragment`. Then you should create a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return BasicButtonsFragment.newInstace();
        return ScientificButtonsFragment.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Finnaly, set this adapter to your `ViewPager`.

Comment: Its not like I dont want to use `ViewPager` . I will be glad to use it if `ViewPager` can be used to implement such design. But I dont think that `ViewPager`can be used for the above design. If you think it can be, please give some code

Answer (score 0):

You can you a DrawerLayout. Check it on the google. I think that is what you are looking for.